# why python-extension function breaks when creating array of structs with length greater than 4?

Tags: python, c, arrays

I'm writing a python extension module in C. Python stops running when I declare an array of structs greater than 4 elements in a function of that module.

I'm writing the module to increase performance.
I've declared 3 structs( "SKU", "Cromosoma", "Aptitud" ) and I want to create an array of Cromosoma, but when I try to create the array with more than 4 elements it breaks.

```
// need_for_speed.c   extension module code
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_GENES_SIZE  2000
typedef struct{
    char codigo[30];
    double venta;
    char nombre[100];
    double categoria;
    double peso;
    double ubicacion_especifica;
    double ubicacion_actual;
    double ubicacion_a_mover;
    double stock;
} SKU;
typedef struct{
    double ubicaciones_rompe_regla;
    double cercania_medio;
    double desv_std_picks_x_seccion;
    double peso_x_ubicacion;
} Aptitud;
typedef struct{
    SKU genes[MAX_GENES_SIZE];
    Aptitud aptitud;
    int genes_size;
    int edad;
}Cromosoma;

static PyObject* prueba(PyObject* self, PyObject* args){
    Cromosoma a;
    SKU s;
    strcpy(s.codigo,"1212");
    a.genes[0] = s;
    Cromosoma poblacion[] = {a,a,a,a,a};
    printf("codigo %s ", poblacion[0].genes[0].codigo);
    return PyLong_FromDouble(1);
}
static PyMethodDef Methods[] = {
    {"prueba", prueba, METH_NOARGS, "Prueba general"},
    { NULL, NULL, 0, NULL }
};

// Module Definition struct
static struct PyModuleDef need_for_speed = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "need_for_speed",
    "Modulo para aumento de la velocidad de procesamiento para el algoritmo genético",
    -1,
    Methods
};

// Initialize module 
PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_need_for_speed(void)
{
    PyObject *m;
    m = PyModule_Create(&need_for_speed);
    return m;
}
```

the setup.py to build this module:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
setup(name = 'need_for_speed', version = '1.0',ext_modules = [Extension('need_for_speed', ['need_for_speed.c'])])
```

command to build module:

```
python setup.py build
```

when I call the function prueba:

```
import need_for_speed
i = need_for_speed.prueba()
```

python stops running without printing or returning anything, but if modify the array named "poblacion" in the "prueba" function to have only 4 elements it runs perfectly, returning 1 and printing "codigo 1212".

I'm using Windows BTW.

Comment: I see no reason to believe that the code presented is responsible for the behavior described, even if we stipulate that it is corrected to make it valid C by inserting the missing `}` into the definition of the `Cromosoma` typedef.  At least nothing related to the arrays.  A *bona fide* [mre] is needed for us to determine what may be going on.

Comment: Sorry for the missing } and the missing code necessary for the minimal reproducible example. I just edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably a [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow).

Let's see how large your structs are assuming they only take the size of the individual members (neglecting padding, etc.):

- `SKU`: 7 doubles and 130 chars -> 7 * 8 bytes + 130 bytes -> 186 bytes
- `Aptitud`: 4 doubles -> 4 * 8 bytes -> 32 bytes
- `Cromosoma`: 2 ints, 1 Aptitud and 2000 SKU -> 2 * 4 bytes + 32 bytes + 2000 * 186 bytes -> 372040 bytes

So one instance of `Chromosoma` will take ~370kB. And you create 5/6 of them; one with `Cromosoma a;` and one for each slot in the array: 4/5.

A typical stack will be only a few megabytes. With 6 * 370kB ~ 2.1MB it's at least reasonable that you exhausted your stack. For example MSVC (Windows Visual Studio C/C++ compiler) by default uses just [1 MB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/f-set-stack-size). Given that it fails with an array of size 5 but works with one of size 4 it seems that you have ~2 MB of stack.

To avoid this problem you could increase your stack size (how you do that depends on your compiler). However increasing the stack size will again lead to problems when you need more `Chromosoma` or change the number of `SKU`s.

Another alternative (probably better than increasing the stack size) would be to allocate all **big arrays** on the heap. For example you could allocate the `poblacion` on the heap - and/or make the `Chromosoma.genes` a pointer to an array of `SKU`.